# Agfacolor 80s: which processing chemistry?

Tags: developing, processing, chemicals

I purchased 2 rolls of Agfacolor 80s on ebay which have been expired since 1983.

I am curious whether this film needs to be processed in Kodak's C-41/Agfa's AP70 or in the Agfacolor process known as AP41.

According some research Agfa switched pretty late to C41, but I never found an explicit date when they did.

So I am unsure whether I can process it in C41 or if I have to process it in B&W chemistry, because AP41 isn't available anymore.

Edit: Agfa AP41 was the reversal processing name, Ektachromes competition, I dont remember the negative processing name for the old agfacolor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://www.photomemorabilia.co.uk/Colour_Darkroom/Early_Agfa.html#anchor15rr) gives the process for the Agfa 80s film, and states that the process is the one used for the (older) Agfa CN-S films. No particular name or code for this process is given, but "Agfacolor N series chemicals" is mentioned.

Comment: That page mentions that the film was available in 110, and pretty much all color film in that size was C-41.

Comment: @Blrfl No the page mentions "A professional version of CN S-2 became available in 1975, in 35mm, 120 roll film and various sheet film sizes. The film went by the name of “Agfacolor 80S Professional” - the film I'm looking for. So sadly no c41.

Comment: @Canonip  [This source](https://www.photrio.com/forum/threads/agfa-colour-cn-s-development.53612/#post-782985) says they switched to C-41 in 1978.  OP's roll is dated 1983.

Comment: The Film is definitely Not c41, that is also what my lab said. But I found out, that you can process them for 10 minutes in cold (20°C) C41 chemistry. You will get severe color shifts, but a usable image